# Tweepy Library not finding OAuthHandler

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Relatively new to the Twitter API and such, but I am using Tweepy to try and pull down a list of followers of one account. This is the code I ran, with privatekey.py linking to my API credentials:

```
 import tweepy
 import privatekey

 from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
 auth = OAuthHandler(privatekey.TWITTER_APP_KEY, privatekey.TWITTER_APP_SECRET)
 auth.set_acces_token(privatekey.TWITTER_KEY, privatekey.TWITTER_SECRET)
 api = tweepy.API(auth)

def get_followers(api, username):

get_followers(api, "harrispolicy")
```

`
I have verified that Tweepy 3.8.0 is installed. However, I keep receiving this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-38-a0f5125f5961>", line 4, in <module>
 from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy.auth'
```

Any advice regarding why this is occurring would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I also import auth.

```
pip install tweppy
pip install auth
from tweppy.auth import OAuthHandler.
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
import tweepy
import privatekey

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(privatekey.TWITTER_APP_KEY, privatekey.TWITTER_APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(privatekey.TWITTER_KEY, privatekey.TWITTER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.